# MDF file size increasing in SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I have an MDF file for database PRD, it's weekly refresh, every week all tables in the db will truncated and loaded. In this case my MDF file size is increasing why?

Comment: your mdf file size is increasing or your database size is increasing which by the way also includes your log file size

Comment: Because you have more data than you did before? The MDF file is the file that holds your data so an increase in file size there indicates more data.

Comment: But every week I truncate all data(previous data) and load it again(data volume depends) in this state what MDF file size would be?